# How to remove nonexistant apps from the "Open with" menu?

Tags: macos, finder, applications

When I right click in an item (e.g. HTML file) to open it with a custom app (e.g. browser), it shows a bunch of apps. However, some of these apps are no longer installed in my computer. These are browser apps (Chrome mods) that I had installed in the past.

Here is an example of the "Open with" menu:

[image]

How can I delete these apps from the "Open with" menu?

Comment: We close questions as duplicate if they have the same underlaying problem and therefore the same solution (which is the case if the Launch Service database gets confused).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to rebuild the Launch Services database.

This is easy to do using [Onyx](http://www.titanium.free.fr/onyx.html) (freeware).
Make sure to get the correct version for your current macOS, each is tailored specifically to one OS. Make sure to follow the instructions when installing, as it must be granted Full Disk Access to function properly. It will also need Admin authentication as you launch it.

Start at the Maintenance page. It's very powerful & it can do many things.
If you want to get deeper into what it can do, read the Help you can launch from the Help menu.

It won't 'break' anything but if you run everything at defaults it may throw away such as browser history you might prefer to keep.

For the simplest experience, uncheck everything except Launch Services.

It will require full control over the Mac as it's running & you will need to let it quit all apps as it starts, then reboot afterwards.

Pictures below from Mojave. Monterey has different options, but the Launch Services is still there, a little lower down the page.

Before…

[image]

Onyx…

[image]

After…

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This definitely solved my problem.

Comment: Onyx looks like a great app - thanks. I like the idea that it's tailored to a specific release - that cuts down on the "confusion factor". Any downsides you've found?

Comment: @Seamus - I've never know it break anything. I did once by accident throw out all my browser history, which was annoying, but entirely my own fault. It definitely pays to read the Help & watch what buttons you press ;)